# jQuery - how to attach handlers to elements which don't exist yet?

Tags: jquery

I've just encountered a problem in jQuery. I didn't find a solution which was posted already, if there is one, i apologize for my mistake.

I have this DOM:

```
<div class='usersList list'>                                    
    <div id='7' class='sidebarElement'> <span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='21' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='12' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='15' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='17' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='13' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='5' class='sidebarElement'> <span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='3' class='sidebarElement'> <span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='4' class='sidebarElement'> <span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='19' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='2' class='sidebarElement'> <span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='6' class='sidebarElement'> <span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='18' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='16' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
    <div id='14' class='sidebarElement'><span>user</span></div> 
</div>
```

It is loaded via AJAX from another file. The problem I've encountered is the following. Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function reloadUsers(query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getLoginUsersAjax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {query: query},
            success: function (data) {
                $('.usersCardAjaxContainer').empty().html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $(".sidebarElement span").click(function() {
       console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    })

    reloadUsers("");

});
```

This didn't work, i think because the elements are loaded via AJAX and aren't here yet when the `click` is parsed or whatever, i don't know how jQuery works internally. My workaround for that was to put the click even into the `success` branch of the ajax, like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('.usersCardAjaxContainer').empty().html(data);

    $(".sidebarElement span").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    })
}
```

It works, but seems wrong to me. I've looked for other functions or methods which can do that, but i only found `live` which is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. Is there anything else i can use or will i have to stick with this workaround?

Comment: use event delegation see here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: How comes that you didn't search in Google (or wherever else) something like "jquery event on dynamic element"?

Comment: @Regent I actually did, and all the solutions were on which didn't work for me, but hey, instead of complaining about me not using google, you could have just posted a solution. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach the click event to an already existing element, yet make it trigger only on certain children of that element, as follows:

```
$('.sidebarElement').on('click', 'span', function() {
    //...
});
```

You can technically attach your event to `$('body')` even, as long as the second argument (which is a jquery selector) is precise enough. I wouldn't recommend this method though as it surely has a negative impact on performance.
For reference, take a look at [jquery's .on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Ah, now i got it, so i attach it to body, but only trigger it on `.sidebarElement span`, right? So my on event is `$('body').on('click', '.sidebarElement span', function() {`, did i understand that right?

Comment: Jup, works with body. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Y U NO WORK: *Never* use `'body'` for delegated event handlers! Use `document` as the fallback (if nothing closer to the changing elements exists). There is a bug with `body` relating to styling that means events (especially click) will not always work.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, which jQuery version is that and is that an acknowledged bug? I'm asking because I recently had funny event handler behaviour (`blur()` being triggered with an empty stack trace on focussing an element in a dialogue), with "reversed roles", meaning: The event handler was attached to a an element that was then appended to `body`.

Comment: I found the problem in practice with recent jQuery versions (no idea if it is an official issue), so now I always use `document` in preference to `body`. `document` has the added bonus that it exists before any DOM is loaded.